# Restar a fecha actual un numero de dias y obtener ña fecha despues de la resta c#

Tags: c#-8.0

Alguien sabe si hay una función en c# que me permita obtener el la fecha final al restar un entero es decir:

seria algo así:

```
FechaActual = datatime.Now
int numeroDias = 10;
```

```
dataTime.Now - numeroDias = Fecha calculado desde resta
```

Alguien sabe si hay alguna función para hacerlo. Les agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes el método de `DateTime` [`AddDays()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netcore-3.1) que te permite sumar (o restar si pones un entero en negativo) días a una fecha.

```
int NumeroDias = 12;
DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Now;
DateTime FechaRestada = Hoy.AddDays(-NumeroDias);
```